# The text input in MUI is not filling the width of the input, instead it stops halfway

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input, material-ui

It's hard to describe with words but here is a picture of what I'm trying to describe [here the input stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgoTp.png)

this is what dev tools is showing me
[edge dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJnLs.png)

I'm using material UI Input component with react, and the text cursor stops halfway for some reason

this is the code I think there's a problem with :

```
<Input sx={{ input: {color: "white"} }}  color="primary" type="text" placeholder="name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} value={name} />
```

the entire component code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./name.module.css";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { Input } from "@mui/material";

const Name = ({ btnClick }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [empty, setEmpty] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setName("");
    if (name === "") {
      setEmpty("cannot be empty");
    } else {
      btnClick(name);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.main}>
      <h2>Enter a name</h2>
      <Input sx={{ input: {color: "white"} }}  color="primary" type="text" placeholder="name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} value={name} />
      <Button onClick={handleSubmit} variant="contained">submit</Button>
      <h3 className={styles.empty}>{empty}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Name;
```

I tried looking into the dev tools to find what property it was and started unchecking everything to see if it would expand but it didn't or I missed something

Comment: You can try two things first one is "inputProps" and second one is "fullWidth".
Here is the link of inputAPI [link](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input/)

 `<Input fullWidth /> // example for fullWidth`
`<Input inputProps={{ style: { width: "100%", }, }} />; // example for inputProps`

Comment: Thank you, the first one with fullWidth doesn't work, the whole input size increases and kicks the submit button down but still stops the cursor halfway, but the second one worked,  although I decided to use sx instead of inputProps, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@tobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16971020/tobi)'s question post.

> found a solution from [@BugraKucuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16260715/bugra-kucuk) in the comments
> added width: "100%" to the style for the mui component
>
> amended code
>
> ```
> <Input sx={{ input: { color: "white", width: "100%" } }}  color="primary" type="text" placeholder="name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} value={name} />
> ```